# Load a visualforce page in apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, getcontent

Is there a way to load a visual force page in apex controller without viewing the page.

The scenario is this I have a visualforcepage with apex:chart embedded. This page 
will save the chart as an attachment on salesforce record as image.

I want this page to reload every month to create an attachment image to the record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to scrap this idea. The charts are rendered in JavaScript, so unless you plan on writing a browser in Apex code, it's just not going to happen. You could try using Google's [Chart Images](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/), but they may choose to shut it down any day (it's been deprecated for 5 years now).

Or, find an alternative service that can do the work, either for free with watermarks or nominal monthly/annual charges; there's a lot of choices out there at an apparently reasonable price.

Alternatively, you could use open source like Image Magick and write a frontend for it, host it on heroku or AWS EB for a few cents/dollars a month. Basically, you'll need to make a callout to generate the charts from any of the above options.

Finally, maybe you could just create SVG images directly in Apex code. While I find that SVG is not the most human-friendly thing to do, once generated, you could store these files as attachments, and when they open in modern browsers, you'll have your chart image rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and the tags that you included on your question actually pretty succinctly answers it. However, I don't think it'll be suitable for your purposes.

You can use `Page.<visualforce page name here>` in Apex to generate the `PageReference`, set the appropriate url parameters using something like `getParameters().put('id', <your record id>)`, and then the `getContent()` method of the pagereference to cause Salesforce to render your page (including your chart).

The gotchas here are:

- `getContent()` is treated as a callout, meaning you can't perform any DML (or DML-like things such as enqueuing a Queueable class) prior to calling this method
- You're going to get HTML as a return value. Digging through the HTML for your chart is going to be a chore (regex isn't really a good tool for that job)
- `<apex:chart>` probably doesn't render as an image

That last one is (probably) the dealbreaker. I'd imagine that the `<apex:chart>` tag renders HTML with some CSS styling to make it presentable. I'm not in a position to dig further into that right now, though. Suffice it to say, I haven't heard of anyone converting HTML into a .gif (or other image format) without taking a screenshot.

I'm also not sure how well the general approach would work if you're trying to render a page from within the controller (or extension) for that page.

Comment: Thanks Derek. Currently  I am able to generate those image chart and save it as an attachment to the record.

Comment: I already tried getcontent but it does not renders the chart as you said. What I want to do is, since i am able to generate the charts as image I want it to do to all the records since i need this page to render the chart as image Is it possible to execute this custom page without opening it.

Comment: FYI, apex:chart is rendered by JavaScript so it can do the pretty animations and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce does not support saving page as an image. I would like to suggest to save the page as pdf. Also note Attachments are no longer encouraged to use, better to use Files instead. Below code may help.

Visualforce: must specify render as PDF as below.

> apex:page controller="myController" showHeader="false" **renderAs="pdf"**

Apex:

```
PageReference vfpage = Page.myVFPage;
Blob body;
if (!test.isRunningTest()){
    body = vfpage.getContent();
} else {
    body = Blob.valueOf('Test mode.');

String fileName = 'mypdf - ' + String.valueOf(system.today()) + '.pdf';
ContentVersion cv =new ContentVersion(Title = fileName); 
cv.VersionData = body;
cv.PathOnClient='/' + fileName ;
insert cv;

cv = [select ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where id=:cv.Id];
insert new ContentDocumentLink(ContentDocumentId = cv.ContentDocumentId, ShareType = 'V', LinkedEntityId = dNId);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work, because the charts are rendered by JavaScript.